# Change value of child node if value of different node is the same using XSL stylsheet XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a few days new to XSL stylesheets, but I am creating a program to manipulate XML and these sheets have been an amazing help. I have two '' nodes that I need to check.

```
<Callout id="151" start="142" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="25/1" mediaDuration="20/1">
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute id="190" name="vectorNode">
            <VectorNode id="191" kind="TypeWinSVG">
                <StringParameters>
                    <Parameter id="203" name="name">
                        <Keyframes>
                            <Keyframe id="204" time="0/1" value="Sketch Motion Perfect Rectangle" leadInLength="0/1"/>
                        </Keyframes>
                    </Parameter>
                </StringParameters>
            </VectorNode>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>

</Callout>

<Callout id="588" start="17" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="0/1" mediaDuration="88/1" >
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute id="620"  name="vectorNode">
            <VectorNode id="621" kind="TypeWinText"  >
            </VectorNode>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Callout>
```

If 'kind' of the second (won't always be index(1) or the second) is equal to TypeWinText check to see if their start values are equal. If they are do nothing, but if they aren't change the first `<Callout>` (won't always be the first) `value="Transparent Hotspot"`.

There are multiple Callout nodes (all under a parent Media) and there are multiple of these checks.

A realistic example:

```
<Callout id="151" start="142" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="25/1" mediaDuration="20/1">
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute id="190" name="vectorNode">
            <VectorNode id="191" kind="TypeWinSVG">
                <StringParameters>
                    <Parameter id="203" name="name">
                        <Keyframes>
                            <Keyframe id="204" time="0/1" value="Sketch Motion Perfect Rectangle" leadInLength="0/1"/>
                        </Keyframes>
                    </Parameter>
                </StringParameters>
            </VectorNode>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>

</Callout>

<Callout id="210" start="246" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="25/1" mediaDuration="20/1">
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute id="190" name="vectorNode">
            <VectorNode id="191" kind="TypeWinSVG">
                <StringParameters>
                    <Parameter id="203" name="name">
                        <Keyframes>
                            <Keyframe id="204" time="0/1" value="Sketch Motion Perfect Rectangle" leadInLength="0/1"/>
                        </Keyframes>
                    </Parameter>
                </StringParameters>
            </VectorNode>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>        
</Callout>

<Callout id="151" start="294" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="25/1" mediaDuration="20/1">
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute id="190" name="vectorNode">
            <VectorNode id="191" kind="TypeWinSVG">
                <StringParameters>
                    <Parameter id="203" name="name">
                        <Keyframes>
                            <Keyframe id="204" time="0/1" value="Sketch Motion Perfect Rectangle" leadInLength="0/1"/>
                        </Keyframes>
                    </Parameter>
                </StringParameters>
            </VectorNode>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>         
</Callout>



<Callout id="588" start="17" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="0/1" mediaDuration="88/1" >
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute id="620"  name="vectorNode">
            <VectorNode id="621" kind="TypeWinText"  >
            </VectorNode>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Callout>

<Callout id="588" start="246" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="0/1" mediaDuration="88/1" >
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute id="620"  name="vectorNode">
            <VectorNode id="621" kind="TypeWinText"  >
            </VectorNode>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Callout>

<Callout id="588" start="275" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="0/1" mediaDuration="88/1" >
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute id="620"  name="vectorNode">
            <VectorNode id="621" kind="TypeWinText"  >
            </VectorNode>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Callout>

<Callout id="588" start="294" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="0/1" mediaDuration="88/1" >
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute id="620"  name="vectorNode">
            <VectorNode id="621" kind="TypeWinText"  >
            </VectorNode>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Callout>
```

The second and third of the first group will change it's value of "Sketch Motion Perfect Rectangle" to "Transparent Hotspot" because the 'start' value of the first group matches up with start values of the second 246 and 294. There will be other start values in the document, but because the second group are only kind=TypeWinText we only care about these nodes. The first one does not change because the start value doesn't equal any other start values.

Comment: Will there be more than or less than 2 Callout elements?

Will the id attributes of the Callout element be known at design time?

Order in XML should never be inferred, but there must be a way to programmatically refer to another element - and only one.

Comment: There will most likely always be more than 1, more than 2. Could be 100.

Comment: Ok; when you say "start values", which other start value am I comparing against - another callout element?  If I have Callouts A != B != C != D, then all of them should be set to Transparent Hotspot (assuming all 4 are TypeWinText), yes?

Comment: In my example `<Callout id="588" start="17"` that start value compared to another one. If A!=B or C or D (considering B, C, D are TypeWinText). If that makes sense? i can give a more realistic example if need be.

Comment: More examples might help.  I wonder what the behavior should be if A = B, but A != C.  In your original rule, you said if A = B then no change, but because A != C, one of them (you don't provide a rule to specify which) gets changed.  Can you clarify this, as well?  Also, "kind" is an attribute of VectorNode, which is a child of Attribute.  I infer because of Attributes (plural) that there can be multiple VectorNodes, and, then, there could be a case where Callout has kind with both types.  Can you clarify that as well?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness! To clarify: short answer is no there will never be a case where they have the same 'kinds' or 'values'.


I will post a better example in the original post!

Comment: Ok, much better. But now you need to define why doesn't the first node change, while the other two do change.  Originally, you said that a node won't always be the first (so, could be the second) or that the second node won't always be 2nd (so, could be the first).  In other words, what rule says change two out of the three, but don't change all three, and, which of the three to leave alone?

Comment: I updated it again! Comparing the value where it says "Sketch Motion" with elements with the value of kind="TypeWinText". Taking these two elements and comparing the start values. Anytime a Sketch Motion element is equal to one of the TypeWinText values nothing happens. All other times where the start values of the Sketch Motion doesn't match any of the start values of the other callout. Change the text to the transparent hotspot. I hope I am being more clear! Still new to asking questions too!

Comment: Ok, think I got it:

If a TypeWinSVG's start value matches any TypeWinText's start value, do nothing.

If a TypeWinSVG's start value does not match any TypeWinText's start value, then change the TypeWinSVG's value.

The algorithm, then, is this:

If not exists
Callout[start]/Attributes/Attribute/VectorNode[kind="TypeWinSVG"]
in
Callout[start]/Attributes/Attribute/VectorNode[kind="TypeWinText"]
then change
Callout[start]/Attributes/Attribute/VectorNode[kind="TypeWinSVG"]/StringParameters/Parameter/Keyframes/Keyframe's value attribute to "Transparent Hotspot"

Comment: Sorry, I had it formatted nicely, seems SO does not let me keep the formatting.  Let me know if I interpreted properly?

Comment: Makes senses! Not sure how to apply it though? Still a day new to stylesheets!